# Sticky header (sliding down) on scroll up

Tags: jquery, css

i would like to achive very similar result like [here](http://codepen.io/adobewordpress/pen/tigrx).
with only one difference: on scroll down, scroll the header up along with content (position:relative), do not hide (slide up) it.

i duplicated it to [jsfiddle.net/Gallex/nmLoykwy/](http://jsfiddle.net/Gallex/nmLoykwy/) with very little adjustment on css.

html:

```
<header class="yapiskan">STICKY HEADER</header>
<div id="lipsum">
 <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce tempus ante augu</p>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(function(){   
var cubuk_seviye = $(document).scrollTop();
var header_yuksekligi = $('.yapiskan').outerHeight();
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var kaydirma_cubugu = $(document).scrollTop();
   if (kaydirma_cubugu > header_yuksekligi)   {$('.yapiskan').addClass('gizle');} 
    else {$('.yapiskan').removeClass('gizle');}     
    if (kaydirma_cubugu > cubuk_seviye) {$('.yapiskan').removeClass('sabit');} 
    else {$('.yapiskan').addClass('sabit');}                
    cubuk_seviye = $(document).scrollTop(); 
 });
 });
```

css:

```
.yapiskan{
background-color:#e74c3c; 
color:white; 
font-size:24px; 
padding:5px; 
text-align:center; 
position:relative;
left:0; 
top:0; 
width:100%; 
transition: .5s;
}
.gizle {
top: -90px;
}
.sabit {
top:0;
z-index: 9999;
position:fixed;
}
```

yes, if i change

```
.gizle {
top: -90px;
}
```

to top:0; it does as needed, but it ends the header slide down transition effect on scroll up as well.

Answer (score 1):

solved it with @keyframes:

```
.sabit {
top:0;
z-index: 9999;
position:fixed;
-webkit-animation: fadeInDown 0.5s ease;
animation: fadeInDown 0.5s ease;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
0%   {-webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);}
100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0);}
} 

@keyframes fadeInDown {
0%   {-ms-transform: translateY(-100%); transform: translateY(-100%);}
100% {-ms-transform: translateY(0); transform: translateY(0);}
}
```

final result: [jsfiddle.net/Gallex/nmLoykwy/](http://jsfiddle.net/Gallex/nmLoykwy/)

or do you know better solution?